# UIImagePicker's UINavigationBar is abiding to drawRect. How can I stop this?

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, uinavigationbar, drawrect

I am using the following code to set the backgrounds of all UINavigationBars in my application. However, when I load the UIImagePicker, its' UINavigationBar will have the same backgroundView as all of the other UINavigationBars in my application.

How could I prevent this from happening?

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarSocial.png"] drawInRect:rect];
}
@end
```

Comment: Keep in mind that swizzling UINavigationBar will come with a performance penalty.  I realize that you want to do some customization of the navigation bar, but you can do this using XIBs, rather than using a category.  Also, keep in mind that your hack here will not work in iOS 5.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I will need to update the app for it. I would need to use setBackgroundImage... method, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and i fixed it by using the following code in my drawRect method

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBarBackground.png"];
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
self.tintColor = color;
```